# Problem with an elipsis when loading the Django server

Tags: django, django-admin

hi everyone my problem is : 
when i try to go to my admin panel this error shows up ,

ps: i made a registration system for costum user

```
   File "C:\Users\Madara\Miniconda3\envs\myEv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 13, in import_string
    module_path, class_name = dotted_path.rsplit('.', 1)
AttributeError: 'ellipsis' object has no attribute 'rsplit'`
```

`
what does this mean ?

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.views.generic import FormView,TemplateView,ListView
from django.conf import settings
from .forms import RegisterForm
from .models import User
# Create your views here.




#user-login view
def register(request):
    registred=False
    if request.method=="POST":

        user_register=RegisterForm(data=request.POST)
        if user_register.is_valid():
            username=user_register.cleaned_data.get('username')
            email=user_register.cleaned_data.get('email')
            password=request.POST.get('password')
            user=User.objects.create(username=username,email=email,password=password)
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            registred=True
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(''))
        else:
            return HttpResponse('there is a problem')
    else:
        return render(request,'register.html',{'registred':registred,'user_register':RegisterForm})


def user_login(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        email=request.POST.get('email')
        password=request.POST.get('password')

        user=authenticate(email=email,password=password)

        if user is not None:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Account not found")
    else:
        return render(request,'login.html')

#user-logout view
@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

admin.py:

```
# accounts.admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin


from .forms import UserAdminCreationForm, UserAdminChangeForm
from .models import User

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserAdminChangeForm
    add_form = UserAdminCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('email', 'admin')
    list_filter = ('admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ()}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('admin',)}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()


admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)



# Remove Group Model from admin. We're not using it.
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

settings.py:
"""

```
Django settings for empliya project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles','accounts','search','gigpost','allauth','allauth.account','allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'empliya.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'empliya.wsgi.application'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'empliya/static')

#MEDIA files
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL='/media/'

#login
LOGIN_URL='accounts/user_login'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (

    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    ...
)
```

thanks in advance for helping me guys.

ljflmdjgmlkjdfglmkfdhfdhfghfghfghfdghfghgfhdfhjfghfmlhjfdmlhjdfgmhdjhlmkfjhmlkjfdhmljfdmhljdfmhl

zeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: Can you please write a more descriptive error? Right now it not likely someone else with the same problem will find your post. Can you furthermore share the *full* traceback?

Comment: Based on the error, this is likely not related to this view, but to your `INSTALLED_APPS`. Can you share relevant pats of the `settings.py` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your [**`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#authentication-backends) contains an ellipsis (`...`). Indeed:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (

    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    ...  # <- an ellipsis
)
```

You should remove this, so that the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` is:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (

    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend'
)
```

Likely you used a tutorial where the author wanted to say that you can add extra backends, and the elipsis is thus specified for the *reader* to add more backends, but the Python interpreter of course reads this as an `Elipsis` object, and the Django system does not understand what you want to say with that.

Comment: thank you so much for asnwering , now i got another error that says :
DoesNotExist at /admin/login/
Site matching query does not exist. , sorry for bothering you

Comment: @zacknamane: you can remove the `'django.contrib.sites'` from `INSTALLED_APPS` (or at least given that you do not aim to (immediately) run a multi-site server).

Comment: i tried to remove 'django.contrib.sites' but another error shows up again when i runserver .. that says :
RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.sites.models.Site doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLE
D_APPS.

Comment: @zacknamane: then likely there is still an app in your `INSTALLED_APPS` that *refers* to the `Site` model? You should take a look at the `INSTALLED_APPS` that might make such reference.

Comment: thanks very much for your time sir , it was an error about SITE_ID i fixed it , Thank again